# Java - JPanel with margins and JTextArea inside

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, margins, insets

I want to create something like this:

[image: Centered text area]

Main panel has its margins (x), and TextArea in the center of that panel which almost fills up the panel.
At the bottom is another panel with custom size (height y), which can be toggled visible and unvisible with some shortcut. Bottom Panel has FlowLayout and few elements.

The problem is I have no idea how to do this.

BoxLayout has no margins.

I tried with GridBagLayout but I doesn't work or I can't understand it enough :(

I tried also with setting JTextArea margins

```
textMain.setMargin(new Insets(insetTop, insetLeft, insetBottom, insetRight));
```

but when there is a lot of text, top and bottom margin disappear. So now I'm trying with Panels.

Can someone help me with this please?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

there are two ways

- use propers [Borders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html), in this case [EmptyBorders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/border/EmptyBorder.html)
- use proper [LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html), [BorderLayout(int horizontalGap, int verticalGap)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html#BorderLayout%28int,%20int%29), [GridLayout(int rows, int cols, int hgap, int vgap)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html#GridLayout%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29),

easiest way would be use `EmptyBorders`

Comment: mKorbel thank you! I used matteBorder around Panel with the same color as JTextArea.

Comment: glad to help you +1 for question

Comment: The separate objectification of something as primitive as a margin (EmptyBorders) made me laugh and cry at the same time. Your answer solved my problem though, so all is well in the end :-)